# Unity 2D send out X amount of "troops" that are equal to the number I put in to a specific target with raycast or something

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, raycasting

I'm trying to create a short 2D game where you can wait x amount of time to get for example 50 "troops". This for now works fine, but now I need a script that detects the number of troops I have (at the startpoint) and send them out, just like small dots going from start point to an endpoint, but not one after another more like 5 in a row * 10.

Troops are counted upwards every second with a float, so could we use that or do I need something other for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TroopSpawner.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TroopSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject troopPrefab;
    public int troopCountPerSpawn = 5;
    public float timeBetweenSpawnsInSeconds = 10;

    private float _lastSpawnTime;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time - _lastSpawnTime >= timeBetweenSpawnsInSeconds)
        {
            _lastSpawnTime = Time.time;
            for (var i = 0; i < troopCountPerSpawn; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(troopPrefab);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the inspector to put the prefab of one troop unit into the "Troop Prefab" slot and it will work.

**TroopUnit.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TroopUnit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 direction;
    public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Put this script onto your troop unit prefab. Then it will move. Play around with the direction and speed in the inspector to see different results.

Comment: This works perfect to create multiple prefabs. Now is there a way to use the new created prefabs and let them move from point a to point b? So that you can see them move every x amount of time into the specific direction?

Comment: Yes, though at this point I would recommend watching a beginner tutorial for Unity, since those are very basic questions.
But I don't want to be like that, so I'll edit my answer to also include what you just asked. But still, I recommend watching a tutorial! :)

Comment: Yes, I will watch some beginner tutorials. Sorry for sparing your free time for such normally easy questions. I just got started with Unity and I didn't really find exactly what i wanted, so I tried myself for many hours but didn't get the result I wanted. Hope that get's better soon.

Thanks man!